# ¿Por qué no puedo actualizar linux elementary?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Tengo un error todos sabemos que para actualizar usamos el comando en linux
`sudo apt-get update`... pero me aparece el siguiente error:

> E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
>   N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
>   N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.

¿Como puedo solucionar el error, y poder añadir nuevas librerias a mi distribución linux?

Comment: Saludos, debes eliminar los repositorios y luego actualizar la lista de paquetes, luego instalar los nuevos paquetes.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes ejecutar en la terminal la siguientes líneas de comandos:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:upubuntu-com/ppa
sudo apt update -q
```

La primera línea elimina el repositorio y la segunda línea actualiza la lista de paquetes. Después de eso, puede instalar nuevos paquetes, actualizarlos o eliminarlos, espero haya sido de ayuda!